# Manipulating HTML with a click of a button (Meteor+Angular)

Tags: html, angularjs, meteor

I'm creating an application where the user enters the name of a dish he/she ate as well as the calories for each dish (Right now, I'm just messing around with the name of the dish portion).

What I want to do is give the user 1 input  :

```
Item 1 : ___________
Button[ADD MORE ITEMS]
```

And if the user clicks the button, it will add more rows of items.

Controller :

```
Meals = new Mongo.Collection("meals-info");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var myApp = angular.module('calorie-counter',['angular-meteor']);

  Meteor.subscribe('meals-info');

  myApp.controller('formCtrl',['$scope','$meteor',function($scope,$meteor) {

  $scope.allMeals = $meteor.collection(Meals);

  $scope.meal = {
    items:[]
  };

  $scope.addItem = function() {
     $scope.meal.items.push({
       name:null,
       cal:null
     });
  }
 }]);
}
```

Each meal has an items array that will represent the number of items the user has in his/her meal. Now in the view, I feel like the best way to go about it is to use the ng-repeat directive.

View:

```
<div id="left" ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="???">
        <label>Item {{$index+1}}
            <input type="number" class="item" ng-model="???"><br>
            <button ng-click="addItem()">Add More Items</button>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The portion with the '???' is the part I'm a little confused about. I'm a little unsure on how to go about things there in order to be able update the view w/another input field for an item and calories (Calorie has not been implemented yet, wanted to get the item portion correct first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to move your button outside of the `ng-repeat` unless you want the button displayed after each row.

Then, to iterate over the items in the meal, you'd populate your `ng-repeat` with `item in meal.items`. Your `ng-model` (assuming the input is for "name") will be `item.name`:

```
<div id="left" ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in meal.items">
        <label>Item {{$index+1}}
            <input type="number" class="item" ng-model="item.name"><br>
        </label>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addItem()">Add More Items</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I ended up figuring out too! Thanks again!